# How to set value to alias_attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting some model attributes via a loop:

```
USER_ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :foo]
USER_ATTRIBUTES.each do |field|
  write_attribute(field, new_data[field])
end
```

`:name` will update here, but `:foo` won't, because it's an alias for `:bar`, which is what we store in the database. In the model:

```
alias_attribute :foo, :bar
```

Therefore when the loop gets to `write_attribute(:foo, new_data[:foo])` it fails with `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'foo'`

Comment: where is the attribute first_name comes from? elaborate your question with more details

Comment: That would be `foo`, not `first_name`. Sorry for the confusion, should be all good now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `alias_attribute` does is it, well, aliases setter and a couple of getters for the attribute. New name does *not* become a real attribute. So, if using the original, unaliased name is not desirable, your only choice is to call the setter, not `write_attribute`.

```
USER_ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :foo]
USER_ATTRIBUTES.each do |field|
  send("#{field}=", new_data[field])
  # equivalent to 
  # self.foo = new_data(:foo)
end
```

As a bonus, this should also work for all other non-attribute setters, such as attr_accessors.

Comment: You're my hero today! Cheers!